# Calculate OOB errors in Cross-Validation using Tidymodels in R

Tags: r, random-forest, tidymodels

I am new to R. I am triying to fit a Random Forest using Tidymodels in R, and I was wondering if I can extract the OOB error somehow for every model fitted in a fold during cross validation.

So far I tried:

```
folds <- vfold_cv(data_training, v = 3, strata=class)
spec<- rand_forest(
  mtry=8,
  trees=500) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("ranger",importance="impurity", oob.error=TRUE)
rf_wf <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(spec) %>%
  add_formula(class~.)
rf_fit_rs <- 
  rf_wf %>% 
  fit_resamples(folds, control = control_resamples(verbose=TRUE, save_pred = TRUE, extract=function (x) extract_fit_engine(x)))
```

in hopes that extract_fit_engine will give me the OOB error for every fold, but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You almost got there! If you modify the function you passed to `extract` in `control_remsaples()` you can fetch the values you want, and use `collect_extracts()` to get the results you want

```r
library(tidymodels)

folds <- vfold_cv(iris, v = 3, strata = Species)

spec <- rand_forest(trees = 10) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity", oob.error = TRUE)

rf_wf <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(spec) %>%
  add_formula(Species ~ .)

my_controls <- control_resamples(
  verbose = TRUE,
  save_pred = TRUE,
  extract = function(x) {
    model <- extract_fit_engine(x)
    model$prediction.error
  }
)

rf_fit_rs <- rf_wf %>%
  fit_resamples(folds, control = my_controls)

rf_fit_rs
#> # Resampling results
#> # 3-fold cross-validation using stratification 
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   splits           id    .metrics         .notes           .extracts .predicti…¹
#>   <list>           <chr> <list>           <list>           <list>    <list>     
#> 1 <split [99/51]>  Fold1 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble>  <tibble>   
#> 2 <split [99/51]>  Fold2 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble>  <tibble>   
#> 3 <split [102/48]> Fold3 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble>  <tibble>   
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​.predictions

rf_fit_rs %>%
  collect_extracts() %>%
  unnest(.extracts)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   id    .extracts .config             
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 Fold1    0.0390 Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 2 Fold2    0.0422 Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 3 Fold3    0.0503 Preprocessor1_Model1
```

Comment: Thank for your help! I have a question about the function collect_metrics().  Is it for a specific package or version? It seems I don't have it.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `collect_extracts()`, it is in the developmental version of {tune|. You can install it with `remotes::install_github("tidymodels/tune")`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant collect_extracts(). Thank you again for all your help!